# What does the mathematical notation at SVG arc implementation notes F.6.5.4 --> F.6.5.6 mean?

Tags: svg

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcImplementationNotes

I'm thinking they're a cute notation for arctan2, but I'm not sure. But then reading the notes below the equations just makes me more confused.

Comment: What excatly don't you understand?  In order to properly draw an arc, the renderer needs to know the centre point of the arc.  However, to make describing paths easier, the Arc path command doesn't make you specify that.  So that section of the document explains how to calculate the centre of the arc from the parameters that you do have.

Answer (score 0):

F.6.5.6 is using a triple bar and not an equal sign. The first part of the equation is Theta 1 and the second part is Theta 2, and then the arc that sweeps between them is the delta Theta (I suppose that just how you do it with a matrix, comma, parenthesis, angle sign, triple bar notation -- but I couldn't find other examples).

Theta1 (F.6.5.5) and Theta2 (F.6.5.6 left hand side) are calculated with atan2.

Comment: Were you attempting to answer your own question, because this does not look like an answer.  If this was supposed to be added to the question, you can edit your question to add it.  Also the `atan2` function is not used here.

Comment: It isn't? I managed to implement a simple SVG parser.
`// Step 4    var thetaStart = math.atan2(thetaY, thetaX);    var thetaEnd = math.atan2(thetaDY, thetaDX);` The inputs being the left and right sides. I've tested it versus the checkbox from material design icon that use the arc path (must seem to use bezier curves).

Comment: The equations involved there do not refer to the `atan2` function in any way (for various reasons), but in the appropriate circumstances, and restricted to 2d space, they may be equivalent (the equations stated are much more general), so you probably can use that function to do the same thing (I only looked at the equations that you referenced so I don't know for sure if you can in this case) in some cases.  When I say that is isn't used here, I only mean that the equations are more general (they apply to any dimension, not just 2) - they are not just another notation for that function.

Comment: Cool, is there a better \ more correct way to 'codify' the math?

Comment: You can use the equations as they are provided.  In my answer, I linked to a wikihow article that demonstrates how to apply those formulas.  That should be pretty simple to translate to code.

Answer (score 0):

In the notation used in **F.6.5.4**

[image]

the half arrows (some people use full arrows here) over u and v indicate that these are vectors, ie directional quantities.  These are usually expressed as a list of real numbers indicating a movement along each of the principle directions, for example in the 2-dimensional cartesian plane, we may have a vector (1,1) which indicates movement up by one and right by one (movement at a 45 degree angle).

On the left of the equation, the strange little symbol indicates an angle, so that left hand side reads *the angle between the vectors u and v*.

On the right hand side, the dot indicates a dot product (the sum of the products of corresponding entries in the vectors), and the double-bar notation indicates the length of the vector (the square root of the dot product of the vector with itself - in 2 dimensions, this should remind you of the Pythagorean Theorem).

This is a standard formula intimately familiar to anybody who has studied linear algebra.  Here is a [wikihow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors) demonstrating the formula where you will see the same notation in use.

**F.6.5.5** and **F.6.5.6**

[image]

[image]

are applying this formula using the vectors created from the given variables at the beginning of the section.  The first formula defines θ<sub>1</sub> as the angle between the first chosen vector and the right x-axis (the vector representing a movement of one unit to the right and no vertical movement) and the stated vector.  The second formula finds the angle Δθ in a similar manner.

The triple bar is a congruence relation (read *x ≡ y mod 3* as *x congruent to y mod 3*).  When two things are congruent mod something it indicates that the remainders of the two are the same when divided by the other number.  Thus *13 ≡ 6 mod 7* because both 6 and 13 leave a remainder of 6 when divided by 7.

The formula for Δθ is saying that this angle is equal to the value computed on the right when both are interpreted as an angle between 0 and 360 degrees.

---

This is not the same as using the `atan2` function.  `atan2` is useful for computing the angle a single vector forms with the x-axis, but not when we need the angle between two vectors (without transforming the coordinate system first).